# Have we ever managed to "add" a proton to a nucleus?

Tags: atoms, nuclear-chemistry

Have chemists or physicists ever managed to "add" a proton to an atom in order to create a new element? For instance, a hydrogen atom has one proton; has anyone managed to give a proton to a Hydrogen atom to create a helium atom (as well as an extra neutron, for stability)?

I would imagine that this would take an immense amount of energy to do, so I would understand if this were not possible. However, even if it isn't currently feasible, is there any theoretical way to do this, possibly with technology that we don't currently have access to?

Comment: Yes, this is the basis of fusion reactors. Search on fusion and you'll find lots of info. A common reaction is combining tritium with deuterium to make helium and a free neutron, as described here:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deuterium%E2%80%93tritium_fusion

Comment: (p,n) reactions are quite common in nuclear physics research. See, for example, https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0034-4885/50/6/001/meta - "The (p,n) reaction and the nucleon-nucleon force" in G F Bertsch and H Esbensen 1987 Rep. Prog. Phys. 50 607.

Comment: You would also have to add an electron if you want to turn a neutral atom into a neutral heavier atom, for charge neutrality.

Comment: Fusion of protium (protons) to helium is extremely slow proces even in Solar core, as conversion of extremely unstable diproton to deuteron is extremely rare. Massive and luminant stars with hot enough core usually fuse hydrogen via catalytic CNO process (Wikipedia). .

Answer (score 7):

You do not need the extreme conditions of accelerators or nuclear fusion. Nuclear reactions with protons can be observed even in the pure water of light-water-moderated fission reactors. By collisions of fast neutrons with hydrogen atoms in the coolant $\ce{H2O}$ (i.e. the desired moderator effect), recoil protons are produced which can react with $\ce{^16O}$ to form $\ce{^13N}$ or with $\ce{^18O}$ to form $\ce{^18F}$.
$$\ce{^16O (p, \alpha) ^13N}$$
$$\ce{^18O (p, n) ^18F}$$